# Iteration of a for loop based on a text file

Tags: python, for-loop

Question: How can I make a for loop iterate over a text or a csv file instead of an array?

Scenario:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
```

For instance regarding the code above, instead of the fruits array I want it to be the text or csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
filename=["1.txt","2.txt","3.txt"]
for file in filename:
    with open(file,'r/w') as f: #r for reading w for writing
        #Other code
```

Or if you want to iterate throught all files from a folder then try this:

```
import os
filename=os.listdir("/path/to/folder you want the files from")
for file in filename:
    with open(file,'r/w') as f: #r for reading w for writing
        #Other code
```